# Rancher 1.6: Disable builtin catalogs

Tags: docker, curl, rancher

I'm installing Rancher 1.6 with a bash script.

How to disable the default "Community" and "Enterprise" catalogs with an API request using curl?

How to add my private catalog using the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rancher exposes everything using the API, which was what the UI also uses. There are two ways one could go about to figure out this information.

1) While having Chrome/Browser Developer tools open, navigate to the Settings page in the UI, disable both Library and Community catalogs and hit "Save". The API request made by the UI would be available in the Developer Tools that you can grab to use in your script.

2) The Rancher API also has a slick UI interface which can be used to edit various resources and shows a cURL summary before making the request. This can be used directly in your scripts.

Here is the snippet:

```
curl -u "${CATTLE_ACCESS_KEY}:${CATTLE_SECRET_KEY}" \
-X PUT \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"activeValue":"{\"catalogs\":{\"library\":{\"url\":\"https://git.rancher.io/rancher-catalog.git\", \"branch\":\"${RELEASE}\"}, \"community\":{\"url\":\"https://git.rancher.io/community-catalog.git\", \"branch\":\"master\"}}}", "id":"catalog.url", "name":"catalog.url", "source":"Database", "value":"{}"}' \
'http://myrancher.xip.io/v2-beta/settings/catalog.url'
```

Similarly, you can figure out the curl command to add your private catalog. I'll leave it as an exercise for you ;-)

Screenshot of the API UI:

[image: Disable Catalogs]

Comment: The first was is not working. Rancher responds with ""status":400,"code":"InvalidBodyContent"" How do I get the "Rancher API UI"?

Comment: In the browser, can you try accessing `http://myrancher.xip.io/v2-beta` for the API UI? For the invalid content, you might be having some indentation issues or some other missing stuff in the JSON data.