# Rancher: create project from REST API

Tags: rancher

I'm talking to a Rancher 1.6 server using the REST API.  I need to create a K8S cluster, and do so in fully automated fashion.  The server is unsecured.  I keep getting a "Forbidden" error like this:`{"id":"65256ad5-0dfb-478d-9931-48afc499a1e4","type":"error","links":{},"actions":{},"status":403,"code":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","detail":null,"baseType":"error"}`.
The call I'm making is simple.  I reduced it to this to eliminate errors related to the project template.  IOW, adding the optional arguments has no effect:

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "name": "whatever" }' 'http://10.10.0.100:8080/v2-beta/projects/test/projects'`

Is there a way to create a project with the REST API and no authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create API keys to be able to work with Rancher API. If you don't want to do that you need to disable authentication on the whole Rancher server. This may be fine in a strictly private, secure environments with no public access, but still highly discouraged.

Also if you access the API URL in a browser, you will be presented with a cool UI utility that lets you create resources from the browser itself. Also, the tool gives a snippet of code that you can use from the command line.

Edit 1:

You might find these useful:

- Nice step by step tutorial 
  (https://www.devtech101.com/2017/06/30/managing-docker-rancher-apis-using-python-curl-part-1/)
- Sample screenshots of the API UI utility (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54316465/6702423)

Answer (score 0):

Access control is off or you would be getting back 401.  Forbidden is because you're sending a request to the wrong endpoint (there is no project with the id "test", and no "projects" resource inside of a project), not because you're not sending API keys.

The right place to send creating a project is `/v2-beta/projects`.

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "foo"}' http://10.10.0.100:8080/v2-beta/projects`